# Unable to delete HDInsight cluster

Tags: azure, azure-hdinsight

I deployed a spark cluster that I want to take down. The deployment took a long time so I want to delete it. The delete button is greyed out.

It has been more than 15 minutes since I deleted the resource group it's a part of, but the cluster still seems to be running. I can't afford to keep this running for long.

Answer (score 0):

We are sorry to hear the deployment took long for you. Deployments should finish in ~15 min.

That said, you will not get charged for the cluster until it hits Running or Operational state (which is hit when 80% of the worker nodes are ready to run). Once it's up, billing will be stopped as soon as you click the delete button.